# Error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined" when using ipfs-api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, request, ipfs

I was performing development using ipfs - api, I encountered the following error, add of image file to ipfs node does not work well.
Looking at the details of the error, it seems that protocol is treated as undefined among if (protocol.indexOf ('https') === 0) { in request.js.

This is the error description

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at webpackJsonp../node_modules/ipfs-api/src/utils/request.js.module.exports (request.js:7)
    at requestAPI (send-request.js:165)
    at send (send-request.js:196)
    at send-files-stream.js:99
    at Function.promisify (add.js:41)
    at index.js:32
    at Object.add (add.js:60)
    at VueComponent._callee$ (HaikuCompose.vue?0664:118)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js:62)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js:296)
```

This is the code I wrote

```
import IPFS from "ipfs-api"
const ipfsConf = { host: process.env.IPFSHOST, port: process.env.IPFSPORT, protocol: process.env.IPFSPROTCOL }
const ipfs = new IPFS(ipfsConf)

export default {
  name: 'ipfstest',
  data() {
    return {
      file:null,
      buffer:null,
      ipfsHash:null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async addipfs() {
      await ipfs.add(this.buffer, (err, ipfsHash) => {
        console.log(err,ipfsHash);
        this.ipfsHash = ipfsHash[0].hash;
      }) 
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the module sources, `indexOf` on [line 7 of the request.js file](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-api/blob/2970c9f81efef28b55aba0ba0be40d7f604c1ec6/src/utils/request.js) is used on the variable storing the protocol, which is `undefined` in your case.

And from your code, I think I can safely assume that your environment variable `process.env.IPFSPROTCOL` is undefined.

**TL:DR : I think you wanted to write `IPFSPROTOCOL` instead of `IPFSPROTCOL`**

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I noticed something wrong with getting environmental settings from your point of sale.
The cause is that acquisition of "process.env.IPFSPROTCOL", acquisition of the setting file was insufficient.

Comment: I also noticed misspellings! Thank you very much.